# C# Get max difference from 7 integers

Tags: c#

I have problem with getting the difference between the lowest and highest entered integer. This is my code so far, but I don't understand why I keep getting error messages.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static int array(int[] numbers)
    {
        int minint = array(numbers);
        int maxint = array(numbers);
        foreach (int value in array(numb)
        {
            if (value < minint) minint = value;
            if (value > maxint) maxint = value;
        }

        return maxint - minint;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[7];    
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {            
            Console.Write("Enter number {0}:  ", i + 1);
            numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());            
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Difference between min and max is: {0} ", array(numbers));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you have? `foreach (int value in array(numb)` Probably you want to have `foreach (int value in numbers)`

Comment: I get: 
Error CS1529 A using clause must precede all other elements defined in the namespace except extern alias declarations

Comment: Your code should cause a `StackOverflowException` since the method calls itself

Comment: Care to provide reason for downvote?

Comment: The first thing I see is the first line of your function- int minint = array(numbers) will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: If you're getting CS1529, then this isn't all of your code. Please post a [mcve], and make sure you include all errors.

Comment: @Carl: I haven't downvoted it myself, but the fact that it refers to errors but doesn't tell us what they are is a bad start. That the error which is then mentioned doesn't occur for the code posted isn't good either.

Comment: For starters the line `foreach (int value in array(numb)` is missing a closing parenthesis. For seconds, the variable `numb` is undefined.

Comment: Also note that you cannot hold the result in a signed int if the difference between the max and min values exceeds 2^31.

Comment: It seems unusual that you're using a recursive method for this. You can do this quite easily without any recursion at all simply by looping through the array's possible combination of differences, or simply getting the max and min numbers and subtracting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i'd go with the existing methods `Min()` and `Max()`

```
public static int array(int[] numbers)
{
    return numbers.Max() - numbers.Min();
}
```

otherwise your `array` method should look like this

```
public static int array(int[] numbers)
{
    int minint = numbers[0];
    int maxint = numbers[0];
    foreach (int value in numbers)
    {
        if (value < minint) minint = value;
        if (value > maxint) maxint = value;
    }
    return maxint - minint;
}
```

usually the difference is ment to be a positive value - so you should take the absolute value `Math.Abs()` or `item = item < 0 ? -item : item;` in case of negative numbers within your array

Comment: true, but you're evaluating the `numbers` twice in this case.

Comment: far shorter method and that counts

Comment: ok that's a performance issue but in the case of 7 hand typed numbers i would prefer readability

Comment: I would prefer it as well but I am not allowed to use any built in methods

Comment: You could always just order them first then take first and last but I'd imagine this is still likely to be faster

Comment: What will this return for `var numbers = new [] {int.MaxValue, int.MinValue};`? (I think the return type should be `uint` or `long`)